# OnInfoClick Doesn't Work

Tags: android, location

I have a program that wants to direct me to a location review page where the person can read all about the location about that particular location on which he clicks.

I tried implementing it with the code below:

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_places_near_me);
        // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);

        progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(PlacesNearMeActivity.this);
        mMap.setOnInfoWindowClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnInfoWindowClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onInfoWindowClick(Marker marker) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(PlacesNearMeActivity.this, ReviewActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    } // #EndOfOnCreate!
```

Markers are displayed on google maps using

```
public void markPlaces(String  result, GoogleMap mMap) {
        try {
            final JSONObject json = new JSONObject(result);
            JSONArray resultArray = json.getJSONArray("results");
            for ( int z=0; z<resultArray.length(); ++z ) {
                JSONObject locObj = resultArray.getJSONObject(z);
                JSONObject geometry = locObj.getJSONObject("geometry");
                JSONObject location = geometry.getJSONObject("location");

                Double lat = Double.parseDouble(location.getString("lat"));
                Double lng = Double.parseDouble(location.getString("lng"));
                String name = locObj.getString("name");
                String placeId = locObj.getString("place_id");

                mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(lat, lng)).title(name)
                            .snippet(placeId));
            }
        }
        catch (JSONException e) { }
    } // #EndOfmarkMarkers!
```

problem is that nothing happens, i tried implementing it using the implements method and onMarkerClickListener as well.. Any solution?

Comment: You don't seem to have any code for showing any info windows or markers. Is there more to your code than this?

Comment: They are displayed on google maps using placesNearMe Places API, adding code now @CommonsWare

Comment: Move `mMap.setOnInfoWindowClickListener(...)` to `onMapReady()`. You don't have a map before then.

Comment: holy shitttt man this problem is solved after 5 hrs, you are god man love youuuu @CommonsWare

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use `getMapAsync()` (and you should!), all map configuration of the map needs to be put into `onMapReady()`. Until then, you do not have a map to configure. This includes setting listeners for events like info window or marker clicks.

Comment: grats dude :) 
btw can you tell me how can i improve my UI designs, most of the tutorials are from 2013.. Material design is a bit better in that view.

Comment: @LovelyPrincess: That is well beyond the scope of Stack Overflow, let alone comments on this answer, sorry.